# Should Class objects be serialized?

Tags: java, serialization

We have a distributed application, and our "managed" nodes have to sent information about "features" to the controller node. Our first approach was to simply send instances of some `Map<Class, FeatureSet>`. ( the `FeatureSet` class for valus can be ignored in the context of my question )

Now a coworker suggested in a review to avoid serializing instances of `java.lang.Class`, mainly for potential version incompatibility issues: over time, our controller nodes are replaced with newer systems, whereas the "managed" nodes stay put. This means that a controller node might be running Java 12, 13, xx in a few years, receiving serialized map objects, generated by a Java 8 JVM.

I *assume* that this shouldn't lead to issues (hoping that the people releasing the JVMs avoid incompatible changes for such core classes), but still I am wondering if there are good technical reasons to **not** serialize instances of `java.lang.Class` given the above requirements.

In other words: are the benefits from changing the map key type to `String` for example (in that case, we could simply use `clazz.getCanonicalName()` as key, instead of some `clazz` object)?

Comment: As an alterantive solution: couldn't you use a `Map<String, FeatureSet>` for serialization, where the `String` represents the fully-qualified class name of the class and [`Class.forName(String className)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) on the receiving site?

Comment: @Turing85 That would work as well, but theoretically opens up for error scenarios when `Class.forName()` throws up for example. Raw strings will never fail, and worst case, some string isn't found in that map of strings.

Comment: I agree with your co-worker.. De-serializing a `Class` into a JVM that doesn't already have it loaded doesn't have any useful effect, and if it does have it loaded why deserialize it? Just send the name.

Comment: @EJP Well, source code is also about communicating *intent* to the reader. Our features are organized by class, so using a Map with Class objects as key is like the natural thing to express that ...