# Are instances of Class immutable?

Tags: java, reflection, set, immutability

I was wondering whether [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instances are immutable. The declared methods names do not suggest that the instance state is changed when they are invoked, but I found no explicit guarantee on the javadoc.

Scenario: I need to store unique class names in a `Set`. Ideally, I would like to populate the set with `Class` instances to avoid unnecessary calls to [`Class.forName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) when I need to access the classe via reflection. However, it preferable to use immutable objects as keys of sets. Hence I was wondering if I could use `Class` instances right away.

Comment: Immutable or not, you're probably looking for the guarantee that only one `Class` object exists for any given class name. And this is the case by default (it's not the case in environments with multiple class loaders, such as jee in some cases). So, I'd go for a list of `Class` objects unless I know that different `Class` objects may exist in the same JVM for a given class name.

Comment: It implements `hashCode` and `equals`, so you should be fine with your usecase

Comment: @kolossus, it doesn't override them

Comment: oh? Thanks for the clarification @AndrewTobilko

Comment: @GhostCat I usually wait a few days before accepting an answer. I did not forget :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, The generics part `Class<?>` really doesn't matter here. Sure, no raw types, so `Class<?>` is better than Class, but for your question, the wildcard doesn't matter.

So in essence, you are asking whether Class objects are immutable. And for all practical purposes, they are.

Class objects come into existence when a class loader loads a class, and they stay put unless the whole class loader is unloaded, and everything it loaded with it.

Which can't happen when such class objects are still used in a map somewhere.

On the other hand: `Class.forName()` shouldn't be too expensive for classes already loaded. And when things such as serialization come into play, people suggest to go with String instead of Class objects for example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162293/should-class-objects-be-serialized)).

One has to distinguish between the immutable **identity** of a class object, and the actual "code" belonging to the class. That code **can** be changed at runtime (by instrumentation, think *hot swap* of code). But the class name, and its each code, and `equals()` equality should not be affected by that. Because the "identity" stays the same.

Final note: as the interesting comments below lay out, there are certain ways to *alter* Class objects to a certain degree. But all of these activities are definitely "out of the norm". Therefore: theoretically, you might prefer Strings over Class objects, but practically, in "normal" applications, using Class should work fine, too.

Comment: Classes are not really immutable, as they contains a lot of fields that might be modified in runtime, but these are mostly some cached values, but I think there are also some modifiable values like signers - as it can be set by class loader.
Also it is worth noticing that with multiple class loaders multiple classes with this same name can exist - but they are still different classes.

Comment: And I wonder if specification restricts instrumentation from adding new fields/methods to loaded class, or it is only hotspot issue but other JVMs are free to implement this.

Comment: @GotoFinal The other question would be: would that change the hashcode of the class? You know, Class.java doesn't have a hashCode override, so i guess it uses the default from objects, so it shouldnt be changing at all.

Comment: No, but I don't think we can say that they are immutable then. But for sure we can use == comparison for classes, as there is only one instance for each of them, but multiple different classes with same name can exist. So "I need to store unique class names" is a bit unclear about real issue, if he really just need names or some unique representation of classes.

Comment: I would say that to call something immutable state can not change - for sure we can exclude cache from the state, but there are other properties of class thet can change. IMHO if something is immutable then some pure method operating on that class should always return same results for same arguments - where this is not true with class instance, as you can change class state by using `ClassLoader.setSigners` method.

Comment: @GotoFinal I think, you are looking at it from the wrong side. First, Instrumentation is an operation outside the scope, as such modifications can break lots of invariants, and an application can never be prepared for that. Second, caching happening transparently should not change our view on an instance behaving like being immutable (reminds me on [Are java.lang.Class methods thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24493816/2711488)). Further, the method `setSigners` in a different class creates an *association*, like a map. Whether it stores it into the `Class`, is an implementation detail

Comment: @Holger there is also getSigners in class, so it is part of class state. You would call String immutable if there would be public method that anyone can use in another class to change its value?

Comment: @GotoFinal well, `String` has the method `intern()` whose result depends on what others are doing, further, I can alter the result of `String.getBytes()` by setting the system property `file.encoding` (pointing to my own charset implementation returning random value, if I wish). Considering that `setSigners` is not public and normally never invoked after returning from `define`, I’d not consider this oddity enough to consider `Class` to be mutable in general. But thanks for pointing me to that really funny way to associate arbitrary objects with a `Class`.

Comment: Very interesting discussion, thank you folks for your input (@GotoFinal, too). I tried to capture the essence, and slightly reworded my answer again.

Comment: @Holger in same way Class does store its ClassLoader and class loader can albo be mutable, I just want be strict with definition here.

Comment: @GotoFinal ok, but every object has a reference to its `Class` instance, which has in turn a reference to its `ClassLoader`, so by your definition, immutable objects do not exist in Java. Ok, the bootstrap loader is represented by a `null` reference, but still, it has associated mutable state maintained by the JVM.

Comment: @Holger but you can't really store object state in class loader, but now you are going too far with this, getClass is provided by JDK and we can't do anything about that, but we can't also just say that class is immutable just because you want it to be

Comment: @GotoFinal I don’t get you. You say, `Class` is mutable because it has a reference to a mutable `ClassLoader`, now you saying, “but you can't really store object state in class loader”. So you’re now saying, it’s not mutable? What’s the difference between “Class does store its ClassLoader and class loader can also be mutable” and “Any object does store its Class which does store its ClassLoader and class loader can also be mutable”?

Comment: @Holger you missed most important part that this is just something we can't control, sure we can then assume that all objects are mutable because of that. I think that we should ignore getClass here as it isn't something we can control, but `Class` class itself was created as mutable one.

Answer (score 0):

As I don’t really agree with other answer I decided to write this one,
Classes are not immutable, but they are unique - only one instance of Class object can exist for one class.

BUT class it not defined by its name, as classes might be from different class loaders, and different class loaders might have classes with same names - but that will be different classes, you would get `ClassCastException` if you would pass some object between code handled by 2 different class loaders if that object type would exist in both of them (as separate one, not inherited).

Class instances can be still safely used in `Set`, as they use default implementation of hashset/equals so only same instances of `Class` will be considered equals.

But to decide if you should use `String` or `Class` you need to know how exactly your app is supposed to work, as like I said, multiple classes with same name can exist between different class loaders.

And by just storing class name you can’t be sure that `Class.forName` will return same instance as expected it might even load some other class with same name from current class loader instead of using expected one.